# How to write an Statement Of Purpose for Masters' in Computer Science given it covers a broad range of topics?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science, statement-of-purpose

All the guidelines for writing a Statement of Purpose emphasize on how you need to properly explain why you would like to pursue an Master's in the specific branch along with proper examples

However, a Master's in Computer Science is a very vast branch. So how do you mention that you want to do a Master's in Computer Science with examples to explain why when every example in itself will talk about some specialization or another?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you think, and write, more generally. Don't emphasize that you want to learn topic X and Y and Z. Think about *why* you want to learn this stuff and how you intend to capitalize on that in the future. Think about your career plans (your long-term *purpose*).

If you have already determined a narrow specialty, which is probably uncommon for a masters applicant, then you can focus somewhat on that, but the *why* of it all and the future goals are probably more important. It is also more likely that it is that the admissions committee is looking for.

Long term, not so much short term goals.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on where you are applying to. Many schools have major groups, e.g., theory, AI, bioinformatics, HCI, etc. In my 15 years of experience in and with grad-schools (CS and areas around), the best is to narrow down on one or two of these major areas. It would make sense to explain why you like these areas, for example, through projects you did during your internships, or courses A, B, C. Next provide a very brief description of work you have done that have been interesting to you. You can find tones of good samples of SoPs through grad school websites for high-rank universities, possibly even the specific universities you plan to apply to.